# More than one enum value for an attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Suppose I have the following very simple code snippet

`enum role: [ :admin, :enginier, :medic, :user ]`

I want one of my users to have the `role` of [:admin, :medic], can I have this working with active record?

(In other words looking for bitwise functionality on enums)

Comment: you can use rolify gem to achieve this functionality without using enums

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is 'no'. You cannot do that with just ActiveRecord's enum method. You can do this by either rolling your own similar functionality or a gem like rolify.

Answer (score 1):

We can use bitwise enums to store multiple values in single enum, e.g

```
as_enum :roles, { admin: 0, customer: 1, user: 2 }, accessor: :bitwise
```